# Java Discord Bot

Tags: java, discord, bots

I am currently creating a bot for Discord. So far, I have got the bot up, and have it "Online" in my server. I created a custom command named !yata that displays a motivational message after being input. Is there a reason as to why my bot will not pick up commands? When I type in !yata it does not run the command.

**Buki.java**

```
package Buki;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.AccountType;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.OnlineStatus;

public class Buki {
    public static JDA jda;
    public static String prefix = "!";

    //Main method
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
    JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("bot token").build();
    
    jda.addEventListener(new Commands());
            
    }
}
```

**Commands.java**

```
package Buki;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class Commands extends ListenerAdapter {

    public void onGuildMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent e) {
    String[] message = e.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");
            
        if (message[0].equalsIgnoreCase("!yata")) {
            e.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
            e.getChannel().sendMessage("The road of a ninja is long!").queue();
        }
        else {
        
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Find out what it does run by debugging and reading the documentation.

Comment: Check the [troubleshooting guide](https://jda.wiki/using-jda/troubleshooting/#my-event-listener-code-is-not-executed)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your codes are so weird!

How could the event be called `MessageReceivedEvent`, meanwhile, the method called `onGuildMessageReceivedEvent`, JDA already renamed the methods! and second you didn't use the **`GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES`**, so basically, it going to be like this:

```java
JDABuilder jda = JDABuilder.create(token, GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES);
```

and third, think is I see you using `JDA`, not `JDABuilder` which is wrong, I recommended you to check what version of JDA you use and use the last one!

Answer (score -1):

```
public void onGuildMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent e)
```

needed to be changed to

```
public void onMessageReceivedEvent(MessageReceivedEvent e).
```

"Guild" was not required in this method's name.

Comment: So why not do as it suggests?

Comment: @Scary Wombat I found the fix. I posted the answer so it would be known. I implemented it after finding out.